# i want to set the sd card as default download location in htc desire 500,how?

Tags: wi-fi, internal-storage, sd-card

In my mobile the apps are only downloading in my phone's memory I think which is full my sd card has a space of 16 GB only 1 GB is used in it and I want that when I download apps it directly goes to sd card memory not my phones memory,how do I set the download location to sd card,so that it uses the space of sd card not phones memory and pls show me the to check whether my download location in setting is on sd card or in my phone's memory

Comment: Doesn't choosing "External SD card" as default under "Settings -> Storage" help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did on my HTC desire and an LG device, and worked for me:

I went to phone storage, scrolled down to storage settings, tapped storage settings, tapped update all and chose the SD card option.

Answer (score 0):

withoust rooting ur htc 626 its impossible to set sd card as a default location,even the photos clicked are also didnt move into it....all are remains in phone memory , 
all u can do is to copy paste every thing from phn to sd card time to time
or ifu can root ur set then i am sure u will find anything that will make it default drive